# How to update the PATH user environment variable from command-line

Tags: windows, command-line, path, environment-variables

I have a system PATH variable with the system level config.
I use the user PATH variable to complement the PATH with user-specific config.

I would like to **update the user PATH variable** from command-line for example with setx.

But I don't know how to reference the existing user path in setx.

In the following command (setx without /M)

```
setx PATH c:\my-user-specifc-bin-path;%PATH%
```

the first PATH means user PATH but the second %PATH% will be substituted by the "full" (user + system) PATH.

So it means that the entire system path would be duplicated in the user PATH... what is definitively not what I want.

I would like to:

- Affect only the user PATH environment variable
- Append/Prepend one or more path element to the existing value
- Do it from the command-line.

Comment: Seems to me that when you use `;%PATH%` you're asking for the existing path (derived from the system path) to be appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell version, set PATH for user:

1. Set new PATH (overwrite) for current user:

```
PS> Set-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Environment\ -Name Path -Value "C:\MyPath1"
```

2. Set append to current user PATH:

```
PS> Set-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Environment\ -Name Path -Value "$((Get-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Environment\ -Name Path).Path);C:\MyPath1"
```

3. Set prepend to current user PATH:

```
PS> Set-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Environment\ -Name Path -Value "C:\MyPath1;$((Get-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\Environment\ -Name Path).Path)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for me :) Two further questions: (1) In case `C:\MyPath1` contains a whitespace, how do I escape it correctly? (2) In case I want to add multiple directories to Path, how do I specify multiple paths?

Comment: @JavAlex, the quote already provide incase your path have space, e.g. `-Value "C:\My folder\My Path 1"`

Answer (score 14):

To set the User PATH overwriting any previous value:

```
setx PATH "C:\MyPath1"
```

To prepend a value "C:\MyPath0" to the existing User PATH:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH') do @if [%b]==[] ( @setx PATH "C:\MyPath0;%~a" ) else ( @setx PATH "C:\MyPath0;%~a %~b" )
```

To append a value "C:\MyPath2" to the existing User PATH:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH') do @if [%b]==[] ( @setx PATH "%~a;C:\MyPath2" ) else ( @setx PATH "%~a %~b;C:\MyPath2" )
```

The if-else condition is required because the User PATH may or may not contain spaces. If you want you can save the commands as generic batch files (be sure to double each % sign) that accept the value to be set/prepended/appended as an argument.

**Batch File**

```
:: PATH-ADD - add a path to user path environment variable

@echo off
setlocal

:: set user path
set ok=0
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH') do if [%%b]==[] ( setx PATH "%%~a;%1" && set ok=1 ) else ( setx PATH "%%~a %%~b;%1" && set ok=1 )
if "%ok%" == "0" setx PATH "%1"

:end
endlocal
echo.
```

Comment: more explanation needed. what is %a, what is %b?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if the user PATH is not already defined :(

Comment: @KJK: `for /?` will tell you all you need to know. :) I didn't want to replicate it all here unnecessarily and thought that info would be easy to figure out anyway.

Comment: The code does not check if __user__ `PATH` already ends with a semicolon in which case appending passed directory should be done without an additional semicolon. But the biggest problem with this code is a corruption of __user__ `PATH` if the string becomes longer than 1024 characters because of `setx` __truncates__ the string to 1024 characters with displaying an appropriate information before adding it to Windows registry. So it could happen that instead of appending passed directory, the existing __user__ `PATH` is truncated (garbled) by this code.

Answer (score 4):

need `SETX /M`, default `SETX` set to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

```
SETX /M PATH c:\my-bin-path;%PATH%
```

Comment: This affect the system PATH variable... maybe my example was misleanding, but I wold like to update the user PATH variable specifically.

Comment: @Chris http://op111.net/82/

Comment: Since %PATH% contains both the local path and system path entries this solution copies all the local path entries to the system path effectively duplicating them.  Now those entries exist both in the system path and local path. The entire objective of the question was to avoid this duplication.   If you leave off the /m you have the same problem but now you are duplicating the system PATH

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
setx PATH "c:\my-user-specifc-bin-path-which-may-contain-spaces;"%%PATH%%
```

Comment: It is an absolute __NO GO, NEVER EVER__ to update __user__ or __system__ `PATH` using __local__ `PATH`. This command line really corrupts __user__ `PATH` by adding to Windows registry for __user__ `PATH` the string `c:\my-user-specifc-bin-path-which-may-contain-spaces;%C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%` in best case. Everyone using this command line has successfully corrupted the __user__ `PATH` setting and so __local__ `PATH` as used by all processes running with current user account after Windows restart or logoff/ logon.